# multiple transfer?

Tags: transactions, ether, tokens, remix, erc-20

First of all, hello. we will write a token for a project we have developed. We are creating new tokens, we want to write a simple contract on remix ethereum. We will distribute a large portion of the coin for free (airdrop), and we will divide a small portion of the remainder into pre-sales and teams. Distribute tokens to thousands of people is costly and time consuming. I have tried to solve this problem and found that by doing the same thing with this contract I have transferred 200 different adrese (see: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x71781f6300a7ab0869fc32710e5a1af43d0721e7a4d416208648e31a98d1801e) a contract. I can write the same on this remix.ethereum. assuming that we have formed a contract; can I make multiple transfers in this way? how can i do it and how can i do it? Which wallet should I use? please help me.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46445/how-can-i-transfer-erc-20-tokens-manually-in-bulk

Comment: yes I want bulk transfers. but this function already exists in the above address. I was wondering, how do I make the distribution after I write that contract over the remix? Which wallet will I use? Is there another method?


I mean, to put it more clearly, I created a contract through a remix. I also wrote a contract for multiple transfers. How do I use this contract? Where do I enter and send eth addresses?

this: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x71781f6300a7ab0869fc32710e5a1af43d0721e7a4d416208648e31a98d1801e
How was the transmission done? which wallet was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand, you guys want to distribute tokens to thousand of addresses in a single transaction. This code you are using is totaly fine i.e

```
function distributeToken(address[] recipients, uint256[] values){
//Mint a token and transfer to each each beneficiary
}
```

In this way you guys can mint a tokens to multiple address, but you should not use this snippet to transfer tokens, transfer must be happen by token owner only on their own will.
You can use "MetaMask" wallet to sign transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am using a ready-made contract for creating tokens, and I enter and write token information to remix.ethereum.org. (ie I did the tests on ropsten), what should I do after I write the above link on the remix? Where should I write the addresses to send token and the amount of token I send? You told me that I could sign and execute the transaction with MetaMask. how will i get that signature? assuming that I wrote the same contract as this one. then what do I have to do to make 200 transfers like this one? please explain at the basic level I am more new.

Comment: You need to get "MetaMask" from Chrome extensions i.e https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn?hl=en. Add Read about web3.js tutorial. It'll help you out to start with Ethereum Blockchain.

Comment: function distributeToken (address [] recipients, uint256 [] values) {
// Mint a token and transfer to each each beneficiary
}

will I write this function to remix.etherum.org? I just want to know that.